# Is there any Library or Widget for add button in food ordering apps

Tags: android

I wanted to use a button like the Add Button that is used in an app like Zomato.

Below is the screenshot.

[image: This is the image]
As you can an green add button and it has some features. is there any widget/library for this button. Or will i have to do it on my own?
Please suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for a library then here it is
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4136

Answer (score 1):

> Yes there is much better library, i've been using in my recently many
>   apps and i found it realy awesome.

**Here you can check and use**

[ElegantNumberButton](https://github.com/ashik94vc/ElegantNumberButton)

Answer (score 0):

Do it on your own for sure. Make xml background with round border to atchieve it.

It should look something like this:

```
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

   <stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/green"/>

<corners android:radius="5dp"/></shape>
```

then use it on a FrameLayout or any other Layout containing other elements that your buttons needs